# Converting recursive Json String into Object in PlayFrameWork

Tags: json, playframework

I have a json string of format:

```
{ "key0" :[{
  "key1": "34",
  "key2": "34",
  "key3": {
    "key3_1": "0",
    "key3_2": "0"
  },
  "key4": "56"    },
{
  "key1": "14",
  "key2": "78",
  "key3": {
    "key3_1": "0",
    "key3_2": "0"
  },
  "key4": "676"
}] 
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

key3 is recursice , it value is again a json string. I wrote a parse code using playframework but it gives error.

My code looks as follows:

```
implicit val contentReader = (
  (__ \ "key0").read[List[Map[String, String]]] and
  (__ \ "key4").read[String]  
  )(Content)

val json : JsValue = Json.parse(content)
val contentResult = json.as[Content]
```

Any suggestion to parse recurive json?

Thanks

Comment: did you read this tutorial ?
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

Comment: 1. Your code above doesn't show that `key3 is recursice , it value is again a json string.`. Your code shows that `key3` is just another json object.
2. What is the error?

Comment: Yes, its again a json string, i am trying to read key0 in List[Map[String, String]].
2. Error i am getting is JsResultException(errors:List((/key0(0)/key3,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))